# Unable to find api GoogleSignIn.silentSignIn

Tags: android, google-signin

I am following the tutorial found [here](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/backend-auth). But I am unable to find the api: `GoogleSignIn.silentSignIn()` as mentioned in the doc.

Is it deprecated or removed?

If yes, would anyone please correct the guide.

Answer (score 12):

A correct way

```
GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
            .requestIdToken(getString(R.string.server_client_id))
            .requestEmail()
            .build();
GoogleSignInClient googleSignInClient = GoogleSignIn.getClient(this, gso);
googleSignInClient.silentSignIn().addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<GoogleSignInAccount>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<GoogleSignInAccount> task) {
        handleSignInResult(task);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

That's a mistake in the example, the method is declared in `Auth.GoogleSignInApi`. See [the references](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/auth/api/signin/GoogleSignInApi.html#silentSignIn(com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient)).

Comment: this answer is incorrect. look for AlexS's answer below.